# How to use different instance of key to retrieve value in a dictionary

Tags: c#

I want to use a key (from new instance with the same property) to retrieve value. but it will get KeyNotFoundException.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<Keyclass, ValueClass> dic = new Dictionary<Keyclass, ValueClass>()
        {
            { new Keyclass() { Key = "k1" }, new ValueClass() {Value = "v1"} },
            { new Keyclass() { Key = "k2" }, new ValueClass() {Value = "v2"} }
        };

        var key = new Keyclass() { Key = "k1" };
        var value = dic[key];
    }
}

 public class Keyclass
{
     public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class ValueClass
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. anyhow it is a simple example that refer to my complex KeyClass. Why if KeyClass contains many properties (10+), is there any efficient way to override GetHashCode or Equal?

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries use [object.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) and [object.GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare keys so you'll need to implement those in your key class, or provide a [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation to the dictionary constructor.

```
public class Keyclass
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
      var otherKeyClass = other as Keyclass;
      return (otherKeyClass != null) && (otherKeyClass.Key == Key);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
      return Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `KeyClass` is a `class`, the key is not found, as you create a new object (which has a different reference), even though their properties are the same. Now there are several options:

1. Overwrite `.Equals` for the `KeyClass`, so your two object instances are treated the same and the key can be found.
2. Instead of creating a new `KeyClass` instance, get it from the key collection:

   var key = dic.Keys.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == "k1");
3. Define `KeyClass` as a `struct` instead of `class`, if possible. Structs are considered equal when all properties are equal.

Comment: Upvoted :)  

"Structs are considered equal when all properties are equal" -- can u enlighten me a little more.

Comment: You'll need to override GetHashCode too if you override Equals

Comment: @NewtonSheikh consider a `struct Vector { public int X; public int Y; }`. If you have `var vec1 = new Vector { X = 1, Y = 2 }` and `var vec2 = new Vector { X = 1, Y = 2 }`, then `vec1 == vec2` will return true, because the fields have the same values, which is not true when using classes instead (unless you overwrite `Equals`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all why aren't you using `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of using wrapped string ?

Second if you really want to use your wrapper class you have to tell the wrapper class how to compare 2 instances of it by overriding `Equals(Keyclass obj)` and GetHashCode() Methods :

```
              public override bool Equals(object obj)
                {

                  return this.Key == ((KeyClass)obj).Key;
                }


       public override int GetHashCode()
         {
           int hash = 17;
           hash = hash * 23 + Key.GetHashCode();
           return hash;
         }
```

Comment: One would assume that the OP is going to expand the KeyClass (or is using it as a simple example). I also couldn't get your answer to work because there is no Equals method to override which has the Keyclass obj as a parameter.

Comment: `Equals` parameter should be an `object` that you then cast into a `KeyClass`

Comment: If I have many properties in the KeyClass, how the GetHashCode() can be implemented in same way?

Comment: Yes you are right the Equals should take object as param ( I edited it )

Comment: @Charla check this out : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode